# javascript execute a tag on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html page with an `a` tag in it, and I want to know how can I make a Javascript code that executes it when the page loads (do the same action as if an user had made click on it)

Here's the code of my a tag

```
<div class="social-login">
  <a href="{% url socialauth_begin "facebook" %}"><div class="btn btn-facebook">Facebook</div></a>
</div>
```

What I want is to automatically register, if possible without the user seeing the original html. (I want this because a user can get to this html from different ways, and in one of them I want to automate the registeration)

Comment: `$(function(){//run register script here})`

Comment: you should use javascript SDK to do the registration, but clicking the  button programmatically against the user's will is bad experience, not to mention if it breaks the t&cs of facebook

Comment: I'm using javascript SDK, that's why I don't have the code and the reason I'm asking how to simulate the clic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

automatically register without the user seeing the original html, add code at the beginning of html

```
location.href="{% url socialauth_begin "facebook" %}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try triggering a click on the `document.ready()` function when using JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".social-login a").trigger("click");
});
```